# How to describe a request that I'd prefer to avoid

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, expressions

Hello dear linguistics,

I am looking for a short phrase, a word if you may, that will describe the following: A request that I can fulfill but I am reluctant to as it involves some actions that I prefer to avoid (not because of effort).

Thank you,
K

Answer (score 2):

They are *asking too much of you*.

This phrase can be used when someone asks you to do something that would be too much for you to bear, whether emotionally, ethically, or in some other respect. Whether you are physically capable of meeting their request is irrelevant.

Here's a [link](http://eleanorestrong.com/tell-if-someone-is-asking-too-much/) to an extended example of its usage (from a web search).

Answer (score 1):

A couple of possible options:

> - I am uncomfortable with what you are asking me to do.
> - I am reluctant to get involved with this plan for whatever reason.

More informal could be:

> - I'm not really onboard with this idea.

Comment: Nice list, +1, Matt.